# AngularJS : factory and controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory

I'm new to angular and I am trying to structure my app following https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app

The issue is when I defined my factory and controller...
app.service

```
angular.module("app.service", [])
.factory('currencyService', function ($http, $q) {
var getCurrency = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http({
        url: baseUrl + "currency/GetAll/",
        method: "GET"
    }).success(function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
});


controller :
angular.module('vendor.controller.edit',
[
  "acute.select",
  "ui.bootstrap",
  "ngRoute",
  "app.service"
])
.controller('vendorEditCtrl', ["$scope", "$routeParams", "$http", "$modal","currencyService", function ($scope, $routeParams, $http, $modal, currencyService)            {
...
}
```

The issue is that inside the controller `currencyService` is undefined...
any idea why?

Thanks for anyone who can help!!

Comment: You're not returning anything from your factory?

Answer (score 3):

A factory is a method that is called to generate the service, so Angular calls it then uses the return value to register your service. In your example, you are not returning the function itself. This should fix the problem:

```
.factory('currencyService', function ($http, $q) {
var getCurrency = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http({
        url: baseUrl + "currency/GetAll/",
        method: "GET"
    }).success(function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
return getCurrency;
});
```

Notice I added the line at the end that actually returns the function.

The way it is defined, you would then call it like this:

```
.controller("myController", ["currencyService", function(currencyService) {
   currencyService().then(function(result)...);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your factory return at the wrong place, so it return `undefined`.

You should do like this:

```
angular.module("app.service", [])
.factory('currencyService', function ($http, $q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer(),
        getCurrency = function () {

        $http({
            url: baseUrl + "currency/GetAll/",
            method: "GET"
        }).success(function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        });
    })

return deferred.promise;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate service, `factory` returns a constructor... or you can use `.service` instead of `.factory`

Comment: and as BiffBaffBoff is saying, your service doesn't return anything